# How to get this number with beautifulsoup and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hey I need to get this number:
27

```html
<a class="r8ZrO" href="/p/B99QGseomNG/comments/">
"View all "
<span>27</span>
" comments"
```

I tried:

```
    driver.get(each)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
ncomments = soup.find('a', {'class': 'r8ZrO'}).text
```

Of course this does not work because the number is not in the class given.
So how do I get the content under the class inside the ?

This is my output:

```
<a class="r8ZrO" href="/p/B99Ql4cl6MO/comments/">View all <span>4</span> comments</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?  Does it get _more_ text than you wanted?  Does it get anything at all?  Does it produce an error?

Comment: I get me more text than I want

Comment: Can you do a `find()` on the `<a>` element, and then using that element as the base, can you do another find on the `<span>` element?

Comment: I can do ncomments.find_next('span') , and now the output is: <span>27</span> , we are getting closer :D

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Get the anchor element, then get the span, and extract its text content? Are you familiar with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html="""<a class="r8ZrO" href="/p/B99QGseomNG/comments/">
"View all "
<span>27</span>
" comments"""
```

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

ncomments = soup.find('a', class_='r8ZrO').span.text

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. But why is my Pycharm not suggesting me .span or .text? It highlights it in yellow? Problem with my Pycharm?

Comment: Pycharm dosen't know everything. 
With beautifulsoup you can place any tag as a .tag to select it... you can also chain as many as you want together i.e. soup.find('a').td.tr.a.span for example as you drill down. any HTML tag can be used with the soup object. as found here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree

Answer (score 1):

Try below instead of `ncomments = soup.find('a', {'class': 'r8ZrO'}).text`

```
ncomments = soup.find('a', class_='r8ZrO').text
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not the problem. But I will use this instead, because its shorter :)